# A covariate as an inherent part of predictor

Tags: regression, group-differences, confounding

I want to compare brain volumes of two disease categories: young vs. old onset. I know that age, in general, is a covariate for brain volume. That is, the older the age, the smaller the brain. However, it is also a part of my grouping variable by definition. Whatever I do, the old onset group has the age $> 50$ years old and the other one is $> 20$ years old. Should I still include age as a covariate or are there any other models that can overcome this high age ~ group relationship/definition?

Comment: Are you building some kind of model? Are you looking for some kind of causal inference, or just a descriptive (or exploratory) analysis?

Comment: @shadowtalker Thanks for the comment! It's more of a descriptive/explanatory analysis. I don't think causal inferences can be inferred from this study.